# can't run test with assertEqual in unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm learning about testing code in python, but when I do an example the test didn't run
the code I used is:

---

```
import unittest
def MTP(a:float, b:float):
 return a*b

class MtpTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
 
 
 def Test_MTP(self):
 self.assertEqual(MTP(5,4), 20)
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

---

but  I get zero tests done:     "**Ran 0 tests in 0.000s**"

I don't know why ?

Answer (score 1):

You should always start test names with lowercase test. In your case:

```
def test_MTP(self):
```